# Access Postgres database deployed inside a container

Tags: java, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Currently I am trying to access to a Postgres DB (which is deployed in a docker container, which is running in a remote host machine) using a Java.
Below follow a screenshot of the "docker-compose.yml" file with the database configuration:

[image]

I already launched the container, but I do not know how can I access the data inside the DB, from my local environment (e.g. eclipse project).

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tried to connect using pgadmin?

Comment: Can you provide more details and configuration files of your local project?

Comment: Please edit your question to contain only formatted text, not images of text. This [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) lists many reasons why this is important. Aside from that: Please include any other details. As written, there's not enough detail to help others help you.

Comment: Generally speaking, you'll want to craft a connection string which references the remote host on port 5432. Make sure firewall rules and network topology allow the connection.